# Trusted connection to SQL Server on VM from Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine

I'm trying to connect from my laptop through a MS Access tool to a Virtual Machine which has SQL server installed on it. However, getting following error:

[image]

It seems MS Access cannot logon to the SQL Server. Now when I specify the SQL Server login credentials (e.g. sa) it works. Note however that even if I can logon through SQL server account, my forms are no longer generated. How can I make sure my laptop is able to connect to the SQL server by default? There doesn't seem to be a trusted connection?

Thanks lots!

Comment: You must add your machine to your server where sql server is as a trusted

Comment: Thanks Jade; how can this be achieved?

Comment: do you have AD or just a machine having sql server?

Comment: just a machine having SQL Server

Comment: what about the operating? what version its windows xp/7/8?

Comment: It's a Windows Server 2008 datacenter R2

Comment: then activate you server AD functionality and add your laptop or other machine on the domain you created

Comment: Please see this link on how to install AD http://www.howtogeek.com/99323/
and for trusted login http://www.howtonetworking.com/msapps/sql8.htm

Comment: Jade, great help! One thing which is bothering me: it would be a very time consuming and cumbersome effort to add trusted login for all our users one by one to the SQL server. Isn't there another way to establish automatic trust? Thanks lots!

Comment: Create an AD Group and put all the users that you want to access your SQL and add that AD Group to your SQL Server but don't forget to set the proper privileged of the group

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **windows authentication** is enabled in SQL Server and you are connecting using **proper credentials**.

Comment: SQL Server is by default windows authentication enabled.

Comment: @Jade along with that we have to make sure that we are using proper credentials.

Comment: absolutely yes, but if you add your account in AD and add it to sql as trusted then it goes..